# ajax удаление картинки из записи yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2, pjax

Вот есть у меня представление с кнопкой удаления прикрепленной картинки

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>

<?php
    if ($model->image) {
        echo "<div class='form-group'><div class='fimg-box'>";
        echo '<img width="100" src="'.Yii::$app->params['domainFrontend'].'/images/'.$model->image.'" />';
        echo Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['course/deleteimage', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'link-del']);
        echo "</div></div>";
    }
 ?>
```

И сам экшен:

```
    public function actionDeleteimage($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $imgName = $model->image;
    unlink(Yii::getAlias('@upload/images/').$imgName);
    $model->image = null;
    $model->update();
     return $this->redirect(['update', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Как сделать это удаление через аякс или через плакс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view:

```
echo Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['course/deleteimage', 'id' => $model->id], [
    'onclick'=>
        "$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: '".Url::to(['course/deleteimage', 'id' => $model->id])."',
            success  : function(response) {
                $('.link-del').html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;",
    'class' => 'link-del'
]);
```

In controller:

```
public function actionDeleteimage($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $imgName = $model->image;
    unlink(Yii::getAlias('@upload/images/').$imgName);
    $model->image = null;
    $model->update();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return 'Deleted';
    } else {
        return $this->redirect(['update', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
}
```